# What client for DECwindows?

Tags: openvms, vax

I have inherited a VAX system that was just migrated onto CHARON-VAX (VMS emulated on Windows) I can access it via ssh, but not with X.
Anyone here familiar with DECwindows? is it X compliant? Or do I need a specific client to access it?

Comment: According to Wikipedia, [DECWindows is DEC's brand name for CDE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia..cussion/Log/2010_February_17#DECwindows), and [CDE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Desktop_Environment) has X inside.

Comment: As Gilles said, DECWindows is X11, so you should be able to use any X client eg xterm. How are you trying to access it with X? I assume you've specified which display to use? Have you authorised access (eg using xhost?)

Comment: This is a funny question here, because historically Unix and VMS are fierce enemies in direct competition. Like, Mac vs. Windows. Except _more so_, if you can imagine that.

Comment: Is `$DISPLAY` set?  What if you run `ssh -X`?  Do basic X11 utilities such as `xhost`, `xauth`, `xdpyinfo`, `xterm`, and `xeyes` exist?

Answer (score 3):

First make sure your CHARON-VMS instance has working IPv4.   For example, make sure it can ping a host on your network.  Also make sure that `SYS$MANAGER:DECW$PRIVATE_SERVER_SETUP.COM` allows TCP: `decw$server_transports == "DECNET,LOCAL,TCPIP"`.

Then log in from your Linux box using `ssh -Y` or `ssh -X` and run an X11 application (for example `RUN SYS$SYSTEM:DECW$CLOCK`).

If this doesn't work, try changing `ssh -X` to `ssh -Y`.  Or experiment with turning X11 authorisation off entirely by typing `xhost +`.

More info: http://labs.hoffmanlabs.com/node/134 (although that page gets "client" and "server" backwards - in X11, the server is the system with the monitor).

Answer (score 1):

Caveat lector: I know nothing about VMS. However I found [this documentation](http://h71000.www7.hp.com/wizard/wiz_6723.html) that explains how to remotely connect with X from a Linux box to a VMS server, and apparently applies perfectly to your problem. [This other documentation](http://vouters.dyndns.org/tima/All-OS-Setting_a_remote_VMS_display.html) gives some more gory details in case you need help configuring XDMCP and the like.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem on an ubuntu box could not run X11 over ssh.

port forwarding can be disabled on client and server, so may need to check in /etc and ~ of server. There is something in the authorized keys file, and some thing in a config file, from what I remember.

Answer (score 0):

DECWindows is based on X.  Any X server should be able to connect to it.  However you may need to frig with configuration for authentication and various other X niceities.  I don't know OTOH if CHARON supports tunneling X over SSH.